# Silex Doctrine 2 : Result cache does not work with Memcached

Tags: php, caching, doctrine, memcached

I need to do a query and use the result cache implemented by Doctrine. I am have following the instructions specified in http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/caching.html#result-cache.

This is my source code:

```
<?php

namespace Fw\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class VisitRepository extends EntityRepository {

    public function getTotal() {

        $memcached = new \Memcached();
        $memcached->addServer('localhost', 11211);

        $cacheDriver = new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\MemcachedCache();
        $cacheDriver->setMemcached($memcached);

        $datetime = new \Fw\Library\GMTDateTime('now');
        $result = $this->createQueryBuilder('v')
                ->select('v.count as _count_today, v.countUnique as _count_unique_today, 0 as _count_total, 0 as _count_unique_total')
                ->where('v.date = :date')
                ->setParameter('date', $datetime, \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::DATE)
                ->getQuery()
                ->setResultCacheDriver($cacheDriver)
                ->useResultCache(true, 3600, 'my_custom_id')
                ->execute();

        var_dump($memcached->getAllKeys());
        var_dump($memcached->get('my_custom_id'));
        var_dump($cacheDriver->contains('my_custom_id'));

        if (is_array($result)) {
            $result = $result[0];
        }

        return $result;
    }

}
```

When I load my page the SQL is run instead of use the cache.

The var_dumps show this:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(17) "[my_custom_id][1]" }
bool(false)
bool(true)
```

It seems that the key is created in memcached but the result not.

If I set manually something in memcached using ->set, and later I retrieve with ->get then this works very well.

Can anybody help me with this issue?

Thanks.

**UPDATED / MORE INFORMATION:**

If I do this

```
var_dump($cacheDriver->fetch('my_custom_id'));
```

I can see

```
array(1) {
  ["SELECT v0_.count AS count_0, v0_.countUnique AS countUnique_1, 0 AS sclr_2, 0 AS sclr_3 FROM visit v0_ WHERE v0_.date = ?-a:1:{i:0;O:22:"Fw\Library\GMTDateTime":3:{s:4:"date";s:26:"2016-08-29 17:59:36.000000";s:13:"timezone_type";i:2;s:8:"timezone";s:3:"GMT";}}-a:1:{i:0;s:4:"date";}"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(4) {
      ["count_0"]=>
      string(2) "70"
      ["countUnique_1"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["sclr_2"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["sclr_3"]=>
      string(1) "0"
    }
  }
}
```

If I reload the page I can see this:

```
array(2) {
  ["SELECT v0_.count AS count_0, v0_.countUnique AS countUnique_1, 0 AS sclr_2, 0 AS sclr_3 FROM visit v0_ WHERE v0_.date = ?-a:1:{i:0;O:22:"Fw\Library\GMTDateTime":3:{s:4:"date";s:26:"2016-08-29 18:00:08.000000";s:13:"timezone_type";i:2;s:8:"timezone";s:3:"GMT";}}-a:1:{i:0;s:4:"date";}"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(4) {
      ["count_0"]=>
      string(2) "72"
      ["countUnique_1"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["sclr_2"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["sclr_3"]=>
      string(1) "0"
    }
  }
  ["SELECT v0_.count AS count_0, v0_.countUnique AS countUnique_1, 0 AS sclr_2, 0 AS sclr_3 FROM visit v0_ WHERE v0_.date = ?-a:1:{i:0;O:22:"Fw\Library\GMTDateTime":3:{s:4:"date";s:26:"2016-08-29 18:00:10.000000";s:13:"timezone_type";i:2;s:8:"timezone";s:3:"GMT";}}-a:1:{i:0;s:4:"date";}"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(4) {
      ["count_0"]=>
      string(2) "73"
      ["countUnique_1"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["sclr_2"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["sclr_3"]=>
      string(1) "0"
    }
  }
}
```

It seems that each time the result is cached again, instead of use the cache if it exists.

Can anybody help me withi this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer to my problem.

**The problem is caused because I am using a DateTime value in the where**. That value is used when the key cache is generated, so each time a new key is generated:

```
... me":3:{s:4:"date";s:26:"2016-08-29 18:00:08.000000";s:13:"ti ..
... me":3:{s:4:"date";s:26:"2016-08-29 18:00:10.000000";s:13:"ti ..
```

In my case, my field in database is only date, so I don't need the time part of DateTime.

I have solved my problem with cache in this way:

```
    $datetime = new \Fw\Library\GMTDateTime('now');
    $datetime->setTime(0, 0, 0);   // NEW LINE !!!
    $result = $this->createQueryBuilder('v')
            ->select('v.count as _count_today, v.countUnique as _count_unique_today, 0 as _count_total, 0 as _count_unique_total')
            ->where('v.date = :date')
            ->setParameter('date', $datetime, \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::DATE)
            ->getQuery()
            ->setResultCacheDriver($cacheDriver)
            ->useResultCache(true, 3600, 'my_custom_id')
            ->execute();
```